# does HTML5 Geolocation work?

Tags: geolocation

I have the following script for HTML5 geolocation:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Geolocation</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no">
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <style>
body {
  padding: 20px;
  background-color:#ffffc9
}

p { margin : 0; }

    </style>
<script>
function geoFindMe() {
  var output = document.getElementById("out");

  if (!navigator.geolocation){
    output.innerHTML = "<p>Geolocation is not supported by your browser</p>";
    return;
  }

  function success(position) {
    var latitude  = position.coords.latitude;
    var longitude = position.coords.longitude;

    output.innerHTML = '<p>Latitude is ' + latitude + '° <br>Longitude is ' + longitude + '°</p>';

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = "https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "&zoom=13&size=300x300&sensor=false";

    output.appendChild(img);
  }

  function error() {
    output.innerHTML = "Unable to retrieve your location";
  }

  output.innerHTML = "<p>Locating…</p>";

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success, error);
}
</script>
  </head>
  <body>

<!-- Learn about this code on MDN: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Geolocation/Using_geolocation -->

<p><button onclick="geoFindMe()">Show my location</button></p>
<div id="out"></div>


  </body>
</html>
```

It always gives me the following result:
Your Latitude : 51.5412621
Your Longitude : -0.08813879999999999
Regardless of whether it is on a laptop or mobile and different browsers -- anyone any ideas? it seems unreliable to me!

Comment: Copied and pasted, it's working fine for me: https://jsfiddle.net/sxjwypwk/

Comment: ok thanks -- I think it is maybe because  I am using http on my site not https